# WPF DataGrid ComboBox binding to collection and selection in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a basic MVVM WPF application which shows a bunch of user-related info in a `DataGrid`. I have two classes (I simplified the classes and have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` like in my real application)

```
public class Address
{
    public String StreetName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Street { get; set; }
}
```

My `ViewModel` contains two `ObservableCollections`.

`ObservableCollection<Person>` 
`ObservableCollection<Address>`

I bind the `ViewModel` to the `Window` and it shows the persons collection just fine. But now I want, the address as a `ComboBox` so that the user can only select values from the address collection above. Something like a lookup table.

Here is my XAML code. I managed, that is shows the address collection, but it won't show me actual record from person collection as the initial record.

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Street" Binding="{Binding Street}"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.addresses, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" DisplayMemberPath="StreetName">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image: ComboBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` property (depending on what you're actually binding to), to the address. So if you were storing the street name then you'd have this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="..."
              DisplayMemberPath="StreetName"
              SelectedValuePath="StreetName"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Street}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i dont realy get it if i now have to use `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue`. I cant get neither to work.

Comment: @HansVader what do you want to bind to? The whole address object or just the street name (for example)?

Comment: i just want to bind to the field `Street` of the `Person` object.

Comment: @HansVader - in that case you do need to use `SelectedValue` as the objects in the combo box aren't the same as the objects in `Person`. What I'd forgotten was that you need to set the `SelectedValuePath` property as well - in this case to the same as the `DisplayMemberPath` property.

Comment: when i open the combobox the values of the `Address` are now  shown. But the `StreetName` of the Person is not. I have attached a screenshot the the question.